# How can I use Ionic 2 Pulling Refresher in my app?

Tags: css, angular, ionic2

Hi all I'M working on  angularjs 2/ionic2 mobile app , i need to do pulling refresher in my app, we have tried this link:- https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/refresher/Refresher/ process i got refreshing the page but it's not get `dismissLoader`, we have given the images of my app refreshing:- [image]

- we don't know where we did the mistake and where we need to add the correct functionality in my project...
- while we pulling the page it's refreshing but it's not get dismiss, `Refreshing` text and icon showing it's not get dismissed...
- what we expecting once we pulled the page it's need to refresh after that refreshing text and icon need to be dismiss...

**we added coding only in html:-****

```
<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="setFilteredItems($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content refreshingSpinner="circles" refreshingText="Refreshing...">

    </ion-refresher-content>
</ion-refresher>
```

- we have not added anything in `type script` part...so please check and update the solution please....
- we have created example [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jGdBUmBbawvGDS3p8tUn?p=preview)
- please update the plunker as well to know the solution, thanks.....

**My Type Script constructor code:-**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GlobalStateService } from '../../services/global-state.service';
import { AccountSigninPage } from '../account-signin/account-signin';
import { AccountSignupPage } from '../account-signup/account-signup';
import { ActivityAddPage } from '../activity-add/activity-add';
import { Activity } from "../../services/actopi-sdk/model/Activity";
import { UserLoginService } from "../../services/account-management.service";
import { ResourceListPage } from '../resource-list/resource-list';
import { IamAuthorizerClient } from "../../services/actopi-api.service";
import { CustomAuthorizerClient, NoAuthorizationClient, UserPoolsAuthorizerClient } from "../../services/actopi-api.service";
import { Config } from '../../config/config'
import { Logger } from '../../services/logger.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

declare const AWS: any;

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'activity-list.html',
})
export class ActivityListPage {

  initialized = false;
  accountSigninPage = AccountSigninPage;
  accountSignupPage = AccountSignupPage;
  activityAddPage = ActivityAddPage;
  activitys: Activity[] = [];
  resourceListPage = ResourceListPage;
  searchTerm: string = '';
  searchControl: FormControl;

  displayDeleteActivityConfirmation(activityId, activityName) {
    console.log("Deleting activityID " + activityId);

    let confirm = this.globals.getAlertController().create({
      title: 'Delete activity?',
      message: `Are you sure you want to delete [<b>${activityName}</b>]? All resources and bookings associated with [<b>${activityName}</b>] will also be deleted!`,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          handler: () => { /* do nothing */ }
        },
        {
          text: 'OK',
          handler: () => {
            this.deleteActivity(activityId)
              .then(() => {
                this.globals.dismissLoader();
                this.globals.displayToast(`Activity [${activityName}] has been successfully deleted`);
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                this.globals.dismissLoader();
                this.globals.displayAlert('Error encountered',
                  'Delete failed. Please check the console logs for more information.');
                console.log(err);
              });
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    confirm.present();
  }

  deleteActivity(activityId): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      // delete from the database
      this.globals.displayLoader("Deleting...");
      this.customAuthClient.getClient().activitysDelete(activityId).subscribe(
        () => {
          // remove the item from the activitys array
          let index = this.activitys.findIndex(activity => { return activity.activityId == activityId });
          if (index > -1) {
            this.activitys.splice(index, 1);
          }
          resolve();
        },
        (err) => {
          reject(err);
        }
      );
    });
  }

  gotoResourceListPage(activity) {
    this.navCtrl.push(ResourceListPage, activity);
  }

  filterItems(searchTerm): void {
    this.activitys = [];
    this.userPoolsAuthClient.getClient().activitysList().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.activitys = data.items.filter((activity) => {
          return activity.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        });
        this.globals.dismissLoader();
        this.initialized = true;
      },
      (err) => {
        this.globals.dismissLoader();
        this.initialized = true;
        console.error(err);
        this.globals.displayAlert('Error encountered',
          `An error occurred when trying to load the activitys. Please check the console logs for more information.`)
      });

  }

  loadActivitysWithAuth(): void {
    this.activitys = [];
    this.userPoolsAuthClient.getClient().activitysList().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        // this.activitys = data.items
        // sort by name
        let searchTerm: string = '';
        // this.activitys = data.items.sort((a, b) => {
        //     return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
        // });
        this.globals.dismissLoader();
        this.initialized = true;
      },
      (err) => {
        this.globals.dismissLoader();
        this.initialized = true;
        console.error(err);
        this.globals.displayAlert('Error encountered',
          `An error occurred when trying to load the activitys. Please check the console logs for more information.`)
      }
    );
  };

  loadActivitysWithoutAuth(): void {
    this.activitys = [];
    this.noAuthClient.getClient().activitysList().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        // this.activitys = data.items
        // sort by name
        this.activitys = data.items.sort((a, b) => {
          return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
        });
        this.globals.dismissLoader();
        this.initialized = true;
      },
      (err) => {
        this.globals.dismissLoader();
        this.initialized = true;
        console.error(err);
        this.globals.displayAlert('Error encountered',
          `An error occurred when trying to load the activitys. Please check the console logs for more information.`)
      }
    );
  };


  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, public globals: GlobalStateService, private noAuthClient: NoAuthorizationClient, private customAuthClient: CustomAuthorizerClient, private userPoolsAuthClient: UserPoolsAuthorizerClient, private authClient: IamAuthorizerClient) {
    this.searchControl = new FormControl();
  }
  ionViewDidEnter() {

    Logger.banner("Activitys");
    this.activitys = [];

    if (!this.initialized) {
      this.initialized = false;

      if (UserLoginService.getAwsAccessKey() != null) {
        // if (CognitoUtil.getUserState() === UserState.SignedIn) {
        // console.log(AWS.config.credentials);
        UserLoginService.getAwsCredentials()
          .then((data) => {
            this.globals.displayLoader("Loading...");
            this.setFilteredItems(refresher);
            this.searchControl.valueChanges.debounceTime(700).subscribe(search => {
              this.globals.displayLoader("Loading...");
              this.setFilteredItems(refresher);
              this.globals.dismissLoader();
            });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("ERROR: Unable to load activitys!");
            console.log(err)
          })
      }
    }
  }

  setFilteredItems(refresher) {

    return this.filterItems(this.searchTerm);


    refresher.complete();

  }


}
```

[image]

Comment: where have you defined `setFilteredItems($event)`?

Comment: there is no component side code in plunker for your page at all

Comment: Hi Suraj thanks for your comment, i have created sample plunker only , if you know the solution let you update that plunker...if you want my app component i will update codes in question....in my project i have used `setFilteredItems` to get load the page ....

Answer (score 0):

You need to call refresher.complete() to dismiss your refresher once loading of new data is done..

```
setFilteredItems(refresher?:any){
   //async call to load.
   // in the then function
   if(refresher)
      refresher.complete();
   }
}
```

The refresher is sent from the html `onRefresh`. With `?` you can call without passing object in your code.

`this.setFilteredItems();`

Also consider refactoring your code. You should ideally call complete after async task ia done and no point in returning another function to the html side and calling complete after return will just end up as dead code.

Comment: Hi suraj we already tired this into our app, but it's showing errors, now i have updated my type script full code and error showing screen shot also please look into that and help us....thanks sorry to trouble you....

Comment: refresher is passed from the html as $event..updating the answer

Comment: suraj are you updating the answer?

Comment: You really cant call complete after return..you have to refactor

Comment: suraj you just give a simple solution to make a pull refresh in my app....i have updated sample plunker if you can please update the plunker ....please look this link for reference :- https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/refresher/Refresher/ ....thanks for your help suraj.....

Comment: I wont be able to code the whole thing..You will have to refactor it correctly and maybe try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you want